# Sprite image alignment issue?

Tags: css, css-sprites, alignment

I have displayed one of sprite's image in span tag. The span is in inside of the some other element like `<div>, <li>, <p>`. The parent elements of the span's, text alignment is center.

The text content of the parents elements are aligned center correctly. But i am not able to
make the span with sprite image to center.

Here i have added the sample code.

**HTML Markup:**

```
<div align="center"><span class="cameraIcon spriteImage"></span>Some Text Content</div>
```

**Style**

```
span.cameraIcon {
background-position: -240px 0;
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
position: absolute
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciative.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using absolute positioning, the `span` tag is no longer part of the text flow inside the `div` element, so it's not affected by text alignment.

You could use the style `display: inline-block;` to make the `span` element a block element that is still part of the text flow. (Some older browsers doesn't support that display value, though.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the span serves no other purpose than to show a background image, so I would get rid of it completely and add the background to its parent element:

html:

```
<div class="cameraIcon spriteImage">Some Text Content</div>
```

css:

```
.cameraIcon {
    background-position: -240px center;
}
```